# How to replace Kate regular expression

Tags: regex, kate

I am using the Kate editor.  Here is a minimal example that shows my problem:

I have a file with a bunch of occurrences of:

```
\command{stuff}
```

where stuff is some arbitrary string of letters.  I want to replace this with

```
\disobey{stuff}
```

where stuff is unchanged.  The regular expression:

```
\\command\{[a-zA-Z]*\}
```

matches such expressions.  So I pull the replace dialog with CTRL-r, and enter

```
Find: \\command\{[a-zA-Z]*\}
Replace: \\disobey\{\1\}
```

So in the document, an actual instance is say,

```
\command{exchange}
```

and when I hit the replace button is changed to

```
\disobey{1}
```

In the Kate documentation: Appendix B: Regular Expressions, \1 should match the first pattern used.  Is this indeed the correct syntax?  I have also tried $1, #1, and various other things.

Comment: In the exact same documentation, it says that `\1` matches "the first **sub** pattern **enclosed in parentheses**"

Comment: Does this still work as advertised? I'm using Kate 23.04. I'm trying to clean up columns of financial data copied from PDF.  Mode: Reg Exp; FIND: `\d(\s)\d`; REPLACE: `\1 ,` so I can add coma to convert to CSV. But the capture group is ignored and the whole find match is replaced.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wrap the value with `( )` to capture it as a group, so you can use it in your replace

So change your find regex like this:

```
\\command\{([a-zA-Z]*)\}
```

and you should do fine.

Comment: @JonathanGallagher, glad to have helped ;)

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat, well next time, I'm sure that you'll beat me ;)

Answer (score 28):

Here is a quote directly from the documentation:

> The string `\1` references *the first sub pattern enclosed in parentheses*

So you need to put `[a-zA-Z]*` in a capturing group, like `([a-zA-Z]*)`.

```
Find: \\command\{([a-zA-Z]*)\}
Replace: \\disobey\{\1\}
```

Comment: To be honest, that bit of documentation is confusing.  In appendix B, which I guess you are referencing, they first discuss patterns.  Then they discuss sub patterns.  The sub is supposed to refer to "substitution".  I honestly thought it meant subpattern as in ab < abc.  So I was like, oh that's strange, you can specify subpatterns with parentheses.  They should have called them substitutions or substitution patterns imo.